# Capture From File

Tags: c#, opencv, capture

```
else if (comboBox1.Text == "Capture From File")
{   
     OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
     openFile.Filter = "AVI files (*.avi)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
     openFile.FilterIndex = 2;
     openFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
     openFile.FileName ="";
     if ( openFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK )
     {      
         char fileName = (char*)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(openFile.FileName).ToPointer();                 
         CvCapture  cap = CvCapture.FromFile(fileName);
         trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
         trackBar1.Maximum = (int)Cv.GetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
         btnStart.Text = "Stop";
         timer1.Start();
     }              
}
```

Hi, I'm trying to capture video file with using combobox and trackbar.First I have to say I'm new on C#.So I think a little stuck.

First of all, I was using these code in C++ after I started to develop my program on C#. I get an error here `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi` and while I want to try get frame count for trackbar here

```
trackBar1.Maximum = (int)Cv.GetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
```

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: For continue my project, all codes should be correct that I taking error .In C# I cannot use Marshal and I cannot get frame count using with CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT there it should be something different but I do not know.Also Am I need to use emgu cv?I am developing my project with opencvsharp.

Comment: can you please print fileName? Maybe it's only the file name without full path?

Comment: I tried to buid program just string string fileName;     
CvCapture  cap = CvCapture.FromFile(fileName);

Comment: unassigned local variable error I'm taking VS2013

Comment: - Is there any way guys I can do video capture from file, if I choose Capture From File' using with: comboBox after I upload my avi file and does not play because I guess _'char fileName = (char*)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(openFile.FileName).ToPointer();'_ There is a shortage in the file assignment. Thanks @Micka

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (comboBox1.Text == "Capture From File")
        {
            if (btnStart.Text.Equals("Start"))
            {
                OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
                openFile.Filter = "AVI files (*.avi)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                openFile.FilterIndex = 2;
                openFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
                openFile.FileName = "";
                if (openFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    ca = new CvCapture(openFile.FileName);
                    trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
                    trackBar1.Maximum = (int)ca.GetCaptureProperty(CaptureProperty.FrameCount);
                    btnStart.Text = "Stop";
                    timer1.Start();
                }
            }
```

I already solved my problem, just that time I was not know codes that between c++ and c# has a different structure.